# Problem to print a pdf

Tags: printing, tkz-collection

The problem appears with two Lexmark printers. A friend compiled this example of my package tkz-euclide:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,fullpage}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-6,ymin=-6,xmax=6,ymax=6]
    \tkzClip 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} 
    \tkzDefPoint(132:5){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
    \foreach \ang in {5,10,...,360}{%
      \tkzDefPoint(\ang:4){M}
      \tkzDefLine[mediator](A,M)  \tkzGetPoints{i}{j}
      \tkzDrawLine[color=magenta,add= 4 and 4](i,j)
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compilation result]

With the first printer, the  print is ugly, we  get a small rectangle of ink, and the other printer stops to print and displays a red light. :(

I have never encountered such a problem and I do not know what to say. What kind of problem arrives? My code perhaps gives an ugly pdf document and some printers don't accept it. Perhaps some drivers are not very good. How to analyse this kind of problem?

Is it a problem with TeX or with the printer?

How to establish the diagnosis?

Comment: Maybe the drivers are not complatible i.e. they are not Postscript drivers. Unfortunately I don't know too much about them.

Comment: Looks fine in a number of viewers for me, plus prints okay to an HP printer. That says to me that the PDF is fine, and points to an issue with the printer driver.

Comment: How old are those Lexmark printers? Linux, Windows, Mac?

Comment: Acrobat Pro says that the PDF uses object compression and has no title and no TrimBox for that it’s not PDF/X-1a compatible. But I can’t comment, interpret or say more about this output. If it helps I’ll post the full preflight report as an answer.

Comment: I don't have Acrobat Pro perhaps it would be useful to have a part of the report but I 'm not able to understand this kind of document.

Comment: You should add informations about the compilation method and your system. And put the pdf somewhere for download. (A pdf compiled with a current pdflatex from miktex 2.9. printed fine on my old black-and-white laser printer, but my pdf doesn't need to be identical to yours).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm waiting the files from my friend because I don't see a problem on my computer and with two printers canon and brother.

Comment: After several tries, the problem seems to come from the driver of the lexmark printer